# sqlsrv_fetch_array does not return index when column value is null (PHP 7.4)

Tags: php, indexing, sqlsrv, php-7.4

I am working to update all my apps to PHP 7.4

I have read other threads stating that array indexing in 7.4 is much stricter than previous versions, and it no longer allows unset indexes to be referenced. That's fine and I get why, but the problem is if I execute a sql query and columns are null for some rows I get the error 'Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null'.

Example

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'val' | null |

If I execute the following query

```
select col1, col2 from table
```

sqlsrv_fetch_array will return [col1: 'val'] and col2 will be a null offset.

I know I can say

```
$row['col1'] = $row['col1'] ?? 0;
$row['col2'] = $row['col2'] ?? 0;
```

but if I am selecting many columns, this adds many lines of code to make sure everything gets set.

Is there a way to force sqlsrv_fetch_array to still return an array with all indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing [SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) into `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. This should return an associative array in which null columns will be represented, but will hold empty values.

For example:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
  foreach($row as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "\n";
  }
}
```